# JavaFx error in Exception in Application start method on FXMLLoader

Tags: java, javafx

```
package application;
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane root;
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new 
FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Mainview.fxml"));
            loader.setController(this);
            root = loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

import FXMLLoader -> Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found.Because of this part of the application
It's still a run exception, but I'm curious about the solution.

Comment: What is the exception?  Please add the full stack trace formatted as code, or better explain what is going on if no stack trace is generated.  Also remove the swing tag if this has nothing to do with swing.

Answer (score 0):

You should update the module-info.java. You must also open the project to JavaFX in order it for it to run.

[Here is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unOn2.png)

In your case, write:

```
opens [the name of your package] to javafx.fxml;
exports [the name of your package];
```